# Add one column of a dataframe as a row in Excel files

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| A | Company | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | Three |
| 2 | Y | Three |
| 3 | Z | Three |
| 4 | Q | Three |

I would like to add the column "Company" to the first row of each Excel (File_1.xlsx, File_2.xlsx, File_3.xlsx) file that already exists.

Could you please help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: If I get it right, you want to write this dataframe's `company` column to excel. if that is the case, you can use python library - `openpyxl`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I want to write "Company" column to the existing excel file. Is it possible to write on the existing one without creating a new excel file?

Comment: I need to use the append mode in openpyxl library?

Comment: yes, you need to iterate through your data and then append: `worksheet.append(row)`.

There are 2 ways you can do - `First:` either reading the existing excel into dataframe and append the new dataframe to it and rewriting it to the same excel. `Second:` You can go to the last row index of the old excel and then start inserting new rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to append new rows and write it back to the existing excel file -

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

old_df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

yourdf = old_df.append(new_df)

writer = ExcelWriter('C:\Full Location\To\file.xlsx')
yourdf.to_excel(writer,'Sheet5')
writer.save()
```